# Kotlin unresolved reference linkedListOf

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, kotlin

Following this post http://obviam.net/index.php/libgdx-and-kotlin/ I
created a project, and edited using Atom. It compiles, and runs on an android device. I want to convert to AndroidStudio for better tooling.

I'm using AndroidStudio 1.5.1, and it says I have the latest version of the kotlin plugin. I created a new project using the LibGDX setup program, imported into AdroidStudio, converted the main class to kotlin, everything works. Then I pasted in my existing my code, and when I build, this line:

```
val bullets:MutableList<NewBullet> = linkedListOf()
```

gets this error:

> Error:(19, 42) Unresolved reference: linkedListOf

When I select Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure it says 'All modules with Kotlin files are configured'.

I've also tried importing the existing project into AndroidStudio, and the result is the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

As said in the [change log](https://gist.github.com/abreslav/f60fc0de060e7ed721c9) of Kotlin 1.0 RC, `linkedListOf` has been deprecated and is not available now. The article you referenced uses Kotlin 1.0 Beta, which is older.

To create a `LinkedList<T>` from varargs, you can pass a `listOf(...)` to the constructor:

```
val bullets: MutableList<SomeType> = LinkedList(listOf(item1, item2))
```

or write your own `linkedListOf`:

```
fun <T> linkedListOf(vararg items: T) = LinkedList<T>().apply { 
    for (i in items) { add(i) }
}
```

Comment: I changed to LinkedList(listOf()) and it got an unresolved reference error. So I added import java.util.LinkedList and now it works. 

So we now need a reference to java.util? That doesn't sound right. 

btw - this is working in 1.0.0, and removed in 1.0.1? Way to go with breaking change management IntelliJ!

Comment: @user2241515, if you just need an empty `LinkedList`, you can call its constructor and pass nothing in it: `val bullets: MutableList<NewBullet> = LinkedList()`

Comment: @user2241515, Kotlin doesn't have its own implementations for Java's collections interfaces, so you have to use `java.util.LinkedList`. As to the change in stdlib, no, it was made before 1.0.0 release, in Release Candidate phase.

Comment: It works with this version:bruce@barsoom:~/Git/shmupwarz$ kotlinc -version
info: Kotlin Compiler version 1.0.0

Comment: I never installed a pre-release version

Comment: @user2241515, then most probably they dropped the deprecated function. It seems more or less OK in regard to backward compatibility. It had been surely deprecated by 1.0.0 release anyway.

Comment: It's a little disconcerting. One reason I'm looking at Kotlin is that it's NOT java. I'm looking for an alternative to FSharp, and on the jvm, that would seem to be scala or kotlin. Having to use a java data object for a core element of my performance critical code, at the last moment, I wonder if that is kotlin's way of saying 'use scala...'

Comment: @user2241515, well, Kotlin has Java (not Scala ☺) interoperability in priorities, and using Java's collections is a mean of compatibility with Java code. If you are concerned with the performance, Kotlin still works on JVM (compiled into JVM bytecode), so if kotlin-stdlib had own implementations of collections, they would hardly be considerably faster than `java.util.*` ones.